# How to manipulate form_for in order to change how the params[] are being sent to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to know how to manipulate the form_for in order to change how the params[] are being sent to my Controller.

I'm posting to the Registration#create controller using this form:

```
<%= form_for @registration, method: :post do |form| %>
    <div class="form form-actions">
      <%= form.hidden_field :occurrence_id, :value => @occurrence.id %>
      <%= submit_tag "Yes, register", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%=  link_to "Cancel", root_path, class: 'btn' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the Registration#create controller:

```
def create
  if params[:occurrence_id]
    @occurrence = Occurrence.find(params[:occurrence_id])
    @registration = Registration.new(registration_date: Date.today, user: current_user, occurrence: @occurrence)
    if @registration.save
      flash[:success] = "Course registration saved with success."
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was a problem saving the registration."
    end
    redirect_to occurrence_path(@occurrence)
  else
    flash[:error] = "Occurrence missing"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Now my params[:occurrence_id] is not being evaluated because the form is sending the hidden field as follows:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"5RFiAq3DiqauNzSpnXIcPzWEl9UuGqoXfYAvRiB6GKk=",
 "registration"=>{"occurrence_id"=>"2"},
 "commit"=>"Yes,
 register"}
```

I'm "expecting" this (with my limited knowledge of RoR)

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"5RFiAq3DiqauNzSpnXIcPzWEl9UuGqoXfYAvRiB6GKk=",
 "occurrence_id"=> "2",
 "commit"=>"Yes,
 register"}
```

So how can I change my form so that params[:occurrence_id] is sent and not params[:registration][:occurrence_id]?

Comment: You don't have a param like `params[:occurence_id]`. Use the following to get the occurence id: `params[:registration][:occurrence_id]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chagne the `if params[:occurrence_id]` to `if params[:registration][:occurrence_id]`

This is how Rails managed to handle properties which belong to a specific object in an html document.

There might be other inputs in the form or multiple objects on a document, this how they will get organized.

If you intentioally want mentioned behaviour then you must use the [`form_tag`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) instead of form_for.

Comment: Hi Jani, this seems to work very well. I was under the impression that I would have needed to change the form instead of the controller. Could this been 'fixed' changing the form post instead?

Comment: then you can just declare a form tag not a form_for